# When modifying the combobox I need to filter data based on a query

Tags: lightning-web-components

**good evening**
*can someone help me in this situation? My code is below:*

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Selecioe o item">
        <lightning-layout horizontal-align="center" vertical-align="end">
            <div class="slds-var-m-top_large slds-var-p-right_medium">
                <lightning-layout-item size="4">
                    <lightning-combobox             
                    name="progress"
                    label="Status"
                    value={value}
                    placeholder="Select Progress"
                    options={options}
                    onchange={handleChange}></lightning-combobox>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </div>

        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Here I can get the id of the item I selected and pass it to the filter function

```
import { LightningElement,wire,track} from 'lwc';
import listaTiposVeiculos from "@salesforce/apex/CarManager.getListTypeCars";
import getCarsByType from "@salesforce/apex/CarManager.callFilter";

let i=0;
export default class BuscarVeiculoApex extends LightningElement {
    @track items = []; 
    @track value = ''; 

    @track chosenValue = '';
    @wire(listaTiposVeiculos)
    wiredUserRoles({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)  {
            this.items = [...this.items ,{value: data[i].Id , label: data[i].Name} ];                                   
        }  
        this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {

            this.error = error;
            this.contacts = undefined;
        }
    }
    get options() {
        console.log(this.items);
         return this.items;
    }
    callFilter(value) {     alert(value);
        getCarsByType({"Id":value})
          .then((result) => {
            this.items = result;
          })
          .catch((error) => {this.items = undefined;})
      }
      handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
         if (this.value == '')
          alert('Todos');
        else
          this.callFilter(this.value);
      } 
}
```

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class carManager {

    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Car__c>callFilter(Id typeId) {
        return [SELECT Id,Name,Car_Type__r.Name FROM Car__c WHERE Car_Type__c  = :typeId ];
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Car_Type__c>getListTypeCars() {
        return [select id,Name from Car_Type__c];
    } 

}
```

Here it must be reset after selecting the item.

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="List">
    <div class="slds-card__body_inner">
      <!-- Start bear list -->
      <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
        <template for:each={items.data} for:item="item">
          <lightning-layout-item key={item.Id} size="12" medium-device-size="3" class="slds-var-p-around_x-small">
            <lightning-card>
              <div class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
                <div class="slds-media">
                  <div class="slds-media__figure">
                    <p class="slds-truncate" title={item.Name}>{item.Name}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </lightning-card>
          </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>
      </lightning-layout>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: What is your question? Also, please do not use the `[community]` tag unless you are actually asking questions about the `Communites` feature set. There are obvious tags here that fit well.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you have a lot of problems. I don't think one question is going to solve them all.

- You need to think about what information you have and what you need and where you are going to put it.
- For example - you appear to be storing a list of car types in a variable called `items`. But also storing a list of actual cars in the same list.
- You need to really think about what you are trying to do before you go any further. Diagram it, write down the logical steps.
- At the very least, you need TWO lists - `types` and `options`.
- After you have done all this and have a clear plan, you can start with the advice below.

First you need to pass in a value to your `AuraEnabled` `filter()` method.

I have called this `getCarsByType`.

It looks like you are filtering by typeId, so pass that to your `Apex` method.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Item__c> getCarsByType(Id typeId) {
    return [SELECT Id,Name,Car_Type__r.Name FROM Car__c WHERE Car_Type__c  = :typeId ];
}
//note this is dependent on your Car_Type__c variable name and/or Car_Type__r relationship name.
```

Then you handle this result in your filter function in your `lwc`:

```
callFilter(value) {
  getCarsByType({"Id":value})
    .then((result) => {
      this.items = result;
    })
    .catch((error) => {this.items = undefined;})
}
```

Your `handleChange` method would look like:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.value = event.detail.value;
   if (this.value == '')
    alert('Todos');
  else
    this.callFilter();
}
```

Also, to import the reference to the `Apex` method, do this.

```
import getCarsByType from "@salesforce/apex/CarManager.getCarsByType";
```

If you are having any other issues, check the case of your code - Javascript is CASE SENSITIVE.

Comment: is giving error, I don't know if it was clear. but the idea is to filter the item according to the type.

Comment: force-app\main\default\lwc\lisItensApex\lisItensApex.js  
Could not find the monkey's method of action referenciado como "CarManager.filterByValue".

Comment: What methods do you have available on CarManager? I was just giving an example - I have no idea what your class looks like.

Comment: public with sharing class carManager {
    public String idTipoVeiculo{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Car__c>getCars() {

        return [select id,Name,Picture__c,Contact__r.Name from Car__c];
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Car_Type__c>getListCars() {
        return [select id,Name from Car_Type__c];
    } 

}

Comment: I made the changes but when selecting the combox a salesforce error message was displayed :/

Comment: Well, read what the message is telling you and fix it. I'm not here to write all your code for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, because I'm late to deliver the project. I'm new without a sales force

Comment: Well, what's the error?

Comment: I passed the id as a parameter 
which is like string 
for the method  this.callFilter(this.value),
stopped showing the error, but when I select the combobox the items in the combox no longer appear and the list I want to filter does not update. I will edit the code above to show how it is